# AirPlay doesn't work when AirPort Exp. extends my network?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, airplay

I have recently acquired an old first gen AirPort Express and wanted to use it solely for airplaying over to my old and amp.

I tested configuring with it's own network and works fine. The problem is, when I ask it to join my house's network, which is not an "Apple network" and is composed of a few routers extending it. The AirPort still shows on my preferences, is detected by the AirPort Utility but doesn't seem to be reached displaying "`Error -6753`".

I am figuring there is some port configuration I am ought do (?). I don't remember configuring internal firewall in any of my routers (except for the one hooked to the modem), but maybe this is a known issue?

*[EDIT] Some more details on my equipment:*

I have the ISP's modem, connected to a cheap *Huawei* wireless router, which has a firewall configured to keep outbound traffic away.
My house has an elongated shape, so midway through the rooms there is another *Asus* (RT-N10+) wireless router, configured to extend the Huawei's network (configured simply as bridge, no firewall, mac filter whatsoever).
The AirPort Express would be in the lower floor, still, closer to the Huawei router (thus what I believe it would connect to).

The network itself is SSID broadcasted, WAP/WPA2 Personal Encripted.

I will be trying to AirPlay from iPads, iPhones and a MacBook Pro over the house, which will be connected either to the Huawei or Asus router.

Comment: Can you add some details concerning your other network equipment? If we are looking at (partial) incompatibilities it might help to know exactly which additional devices you are using.

Comment: There it is. Let me know if there's anything else I could add.

Comment: I think you will need to connect the AE to the Huawei router using the wired connectors. I myself failed to connect to another wifi with the AE. (But can still extend an existing (apple) wifi network)

Comment: Apple says otherwise http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1731 still, haven't managed it.

Answer (score 1):

It will work wirelessly if you are able to get Wifi from some of the old routers. In other words: you need Wifi signal from your existing network for both your AirPort Express and the Apple device to use AirPlay in this configuration.

The Airport Express will work on client mode and **will not extend your network, but it will allow AirPlay**. This is because AirPorts do not wirelessly extend non Apple networks. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72183/will-an-airport-express-extend-the-wi-fi-of-another-non-apple-access-point) for reference.

I have a similar setup in my home, and my solution was to run an Ethernet cable to the AExp to be able to use it to extend my network, and do AirPlay.

On the Error -6753, I've found [someone](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2010/02/apple-airport-extreme-error-6753.html?m=1) suggesting you have to enable IPv6 on your router.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you showed, it states that WiFi signal will be disabled for the AE, providing only ethernet conection to a device wired into the AE. Let's say it would only saves you from installing a long ethernet wire, but it is not an active part of your wifi network for other devices other than the phisically conected.

So, your wifi devices will not be able to connect to the AE to perform Airplay, they will conect to your other routers and behave like there was not AE in the network. In short, you are trying to perform Airplay on a Asus/Huawei router.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Huawei and your Asus advanced settings to make sure multicast traffic is not being filtered. Does AirPlay work on any other devices? How are they connected to the network?

Answer (score 0):

I think AirPlay doesn't work over a bridged Wi-Fi network.

My set up is:

```
                  Client Airport Express (Airplay server)
                 /
Airport Extreme 1 
                 \
                  Bridged Airport Extreme 2
```

When iPad Pro is connected to Airport 1, Airplay can connect. When it is connected to Airport 2 bridged it can't. Also when trying to resolve the situation by moving the iPad directly next to the Airport 1 and power cycling the Wi-Fi radio it still connects to Airport 2. The only way to force the iPad Pro to connect to Airport 1 is to power Airport 2 off which is less than ideal.